# Incorrect retrieved value from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Why the retrieved value of name is null ("nameU" is null), while id is right and email is retrieved correctly?

```
       //get user info
    userDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    Query query = userDbRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(uid);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                email = ""+ ds.child("email").getValue();
                nameU = ""+ ds.child("name").getValue();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

[image: firebase realtime database]

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, and I don't see why `email` would hold a value but not `name`. Can you edit your question to show more code that actually shows the problem? For example, can you log the values to show the problem - and show us the updated code and its output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I wrote `uid = user.getUid();` before the code above and it works. (At the first `uid = user.getUid();` was only in `onStart()`). Thank you for helping. Should I delete the question?